# scalability mssql building 1 big table as a user history

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-design

I am developing a forum. I want to save each time a user visits a topic to be able to show new replies since last viewed topic on a per topic basis.

The way I have set this up currently is to save userid and topicid to a table "visitstopic". Then every time i display a list of topics it will call a request to search userid and topicid from this table.

Is there any scalability issues with this. First if the site gets to say 1 million users with 1000 topics each saved that will be 1 billion rows in the 1 table. Will this effect performance?

Also every time the topics list for a certain category is generated it will call a search of this table for every result recovered so that the view can either show a new reply symbol or not. Will this slow the site down a lot?

Comment: There must be not a big overhead to look for the date of the last visiting of choisen thread and comparing this date to the last post in this thread.
=> You will only have (nVisitedThread * nUser) entries in the table.
I assume you will save a [visiting date], [userId] and [threadId] each time user reads the thread if there are new posts there. 
When it will be the bottleneck you can always save readed threads into localstorage (clientside) =) For 80% of cases it will work - many people do only use forums on their pcs

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing it client side, the only issue which I wouldn't like is if users went between devices

Comment: This is not a big problem. I don feel comfortable to read or write posts into the forum if i am not using a pc or laptop, and then mostly its my own device. But you cant subscribe the user to the new messages if you dont know if the user have read this thread. 
Just try the DB method and if this will cause performance issues(i assume it will not) - switch to client storage(it is also slow btw)
1 million users with 1000 topics each is to much. It will be more like 1000 users with 100 read topics

Comment: "I want to save each time a user visits a topic to be able to show new replies since last viewed topic on a per topic basis.". Then you don't need to save a history of visits, just the last visit. Once a thread is visited you don't care about prior visits do you?

Comment: sorry I should have said, I am only saving last visit. If a entry exists for that topic with topic id and userid it will replace the lastvisit entry. Still tho if the site got huge and had 1 million users who have visited 1000 topics there will be 1 billion rows

Comment: will probably just do it this way and if the site gets big then worry if it effects performance. Could be a huge headache if it does tho